# remove blank space in item and table border of table

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have following table:

[image]

Actually this is a table in which Payment mode is in one `<tr>`

Graph in another `<tr>`

and Grid in the same `<tr>` in another `<td>`

I just wanted to remove extra space between grid and table border.

For this i seted  of grid to different widths, but space always comes along with it. (As i have mentioned in Red mark).

How can i remove that space?

Please help me.

For more clarity below is code for my table structure:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="25%">
    <tr>
        <td align="left" class="NormalText" colspan="2" style="font-weight: bold">
            By Payment mode
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td align="left" style="width: 30%" valign="top">
            <asp:Label ID="LblChartMonthTransPaywise" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" >
            <asp:GridView ID="GrdChartMonthTransPaywise" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                CellPadding="2" CellSpacing="2" ShowFooter="true" ShowHeader="false" Width="100%">
                <RowStyle CssClass="NormalText" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <%#Eval("PaymentMode")%>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            Total:
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle CssClass="NormalText" Font-Bold="true" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                        <ItemStyle Width="40%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblAmt" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="30%" />
                        <FooterTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblFootAmt" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText" Font-Bold="true"></asp:Label>
                        </FooterTemplate>
                        <FooterStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" Width="30%" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:Label ID="LblAmtPercentage" runat="server" CssClass="NormalText"></asp:Label>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Just set the second td with 70%..

Comment: @Raghubar sir, I done that, but please tell me any technique, how can i bring that % sign of 100 besides 100i.e. its going on another row, i want to avoid it(3rd column of grid)

Comment: It is better to provide generated html code for ability to use sandbox, like jsfiddle

Comment: @Anton ok, but that would not show graph as it doesnt facility to generate graphs (backed function i written to generate graph on server side)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I done this by setting `margin-right:100px` to  above gridview as follows.

```
<td align="left" valign="top" style="margin-right:100px" >
```